# Reading from InputStream - stuck in cycle

Tags: java, inputstream

I have this piece of code:
*(this code is inside another cycle, that is cycling 3 times)*

```
            ...
            text = "";
            while((c = is.read())!=-1){ 
                if(prev == '\r' && c == '\n'){
                    break;
                }
                text = text + (char) c;  
                prev = (char) c;
            }
            System.out.println(text);
            ...
```

`is` is InputStream, `c` is int, `prev` is char

With this code I build up a string from the InputStream. The reading should stop everytime when I get \r\n. Then it start's over again. Everything works fine except one thing. The stream I get looks like this:

`1233\r\n544\r\nX`
*There is no delimeter after this input stream*

With this I get the string `1233` from the first cycle and string `544` from the second cycle. But I won't get the last `X`, because the cycle won't stop there - and I don't know why. I thought that with `is.read()=!-1` the cycle should stop when the stream ends. But it doesn't. The program is stuck inside that cycle.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap it in a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) since you're looking for \r\n?

Comment: Is the end of the stream ever reached? For instance, if using a Socket/ServerSocket the end is not reached until the client is closed.

Comment: I would also recommend a) using a StringBuilder rather than String additions in a loop b) buffering of the stream reading (either using a byte array or a Buffered class (eg BufferedReader)).

Comment: @Water I just tried that and it is still the same.

Comment: *"this code is inside another cycle, that is cycling 3 times"* are you sure the outside cycle isn't the one that's causing the problems?

Comment: @copeg I am not 100% sure because I am not in control of the input stream. Yes it is using Socker/ServerSocket functionality. If the end of stream wouldn't come, how could I do this? I have to check if the start of the string starts with 3 numbers.

Comment: @Jonny Henly Yes I am 100% sure

Comment: try `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));` to wrap the `InputStream`. Then something like `while((text = bf.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(text);
            }`

Comment: @JohnnyHenly I cannot use readLine(), because it triggers on either \n, \r, or \r\n. And I need to end only with \r\n. That's why I am going byte by byte. They can send something like `123 \n \r aa \r\n132\r\n`

Comment: @Karlos, is there a character after X, or does X change? Unless the end of the stream is reached the loop will hang. If the last character is known to be one byte you can just read a single byte in the final pass. If not you need a delimiter after this phrase, or the stream to close.

Comment: What is in the variable c after you know that X has been read?

Comment: @copeg Yes the X can change, there can be much more after it too. Delimeter is \r\n

Comment: Your post is unclear: does that delimiter occur after the last phrase (in its current state, your post suggests otherwise).

Comment: No, the delimeter does not occur. That's why I think that there must be a end of stream after that. This is a school project so I dont thing the problem is on their end (not ending stream)

Comment: **what does your step debugger tell you the variables are set to when you put break points on them?**

Comment: Ok I know what was wrong. The end of stream really does not come so I have to set a timeout for my thread. After that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your question is unclear but here goes:

```
while( ( c = is.read() ) != -1 )
{ 
    if(prev == '\r' && c == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
    text = text + (char) c;  
    prev = (char) c;
}
```

Notice the order of execution. Check for `\r\n` and exit loop then append current character to `text`.

#### Do you see anything wrong with this logic?

Also you said

> the cycle should stop when the stream ends. But it doesn't. The
>   program is stuck inside that cycle.

If the last two bytes are never `\r\n` or if the **stream never closes** it will never *end* and it will drop the last `\n` either way!

#### So which is it the loop never ends or the `\n` never gets appended?

If you want the loop to end at the end of the stream **and** at when a `\r\n` is detected you need to re-order your logic.

#### Garbage In Garbage Out:

*Assuming that there are actually `\r\n` pairs in your `InputStream`.* Are you sure they are there?, Step debugging would tell you for certain!

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final InputStream is = System.in;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
    try
    {
        int i;
        while ((i = is.read()) >= 0)
        {
            sb.append((char)i);
            if (sb.substring(sb.length()-2).equals("\r\n"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```

> You need to stop and learn how to use the step debugger that is in
>   your IDE. This would not be a question if you just stepped through
>   your code and put a few break points where things were not as you
>   wanted or expected them.

Comment: I just noticed this while I was trying to add code to my comment. Good spot.

Comment: I know there are some thing wrong with this, I am just trying everything out. Not appending \n is not a problem now. Both - The loop never ends AND the \n doesn't get appended.

Comment: **guessing** is **not** how professionals create software. *I am just trying everyting out == guessing*. You need to make sure your questoin is **clear** about your requirements